# Cannot convert from NaN to 0 in Postgresql Database

Tags: sql, postgresql, nan

I am facing a problem with NaN in Postgresql Database.

The column I want to update has type numeric. Anyhow when I have created the db rows in database it shows me for some lines "NaN".

And when I want to update "NaN" to 0 then it gives me a syntax error because the column is numeric.

Following I used as query:

```
UPDATE anytable 
  SET "anycolumn" = 0 
WHERE "anycolumn" = 'NaN';
```

Error in "German":

> ungültige Eingabesyntax für Typ integer: »NaN«
>   SQL state: 22P02
>   Character: 85

Br

Marcel

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your column actually contains `null` values (which are *displayed* as `'NaN`' in your client). So you would spell this as:

```
UPDATE anytable SET anycolumn = 0 WHERE anycolumn IS NULL;
```

Comment: "*There is no such thing as 'NaN' in SQL*" - yes, there is: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f68dedb615ab20bc6341a31183ff89e3

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: learning something every day... thank you, I removed that part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work with `integer` columns, because `NaN` is not supported for integers.

But it should work fine for `numeric`, `real` and `double precision`:

```
SELECT 'NaN'::numeric;

 numeric 
---------
     NaN
(1 row)

SELECT 'NaN'::integer;

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "NaN"
LINE 1: SELECT 'NaN'::integer;
               ^
SELECT 'NaN'::double precision;

 float8 
--------
    NaN
(1 row)
```